# XenServer, 32-Bit VM's cant exceed 64GB RAM in total

Tags: linux, xenserver, 32-bit

XenServer 6.5 SP1 - 128 GB RAM on Host

Several 32-Bit Linux VM's are deployed, most of them are provisioned with 4 GB or 8 GB of RAM. Once the summarized RAM usage of those 32-Bit VM's reaches 64 GB, no further 32-Bit VM can be started and/or no existing 32-Bit VM can have theyr memory extended. Provisioning an additional 64-Bit VM with whatever RAM value still works fine and results in no problem whatsoever.

It seems that XenServer 6.5 has some sort of Limit like:
- If you are going to deploy 32-Bit VM's, you may not exceed 64GB of RAM in total among those VM's.

This is a theory and i am looking for someone with insights to confirm this with reason and/or links to documentations. I have not been able to find the suggested limit in the 6.5 configuration limit pdf.

Comment: Not sure what sense it makes to provision a 32 bit VM with 8 GB of RAM.

Comment: @TilmanSchmidt you do realise that you can use up to 128GB of RAM on a 32bit OS right? PAE is the keyword:
see random first link on google f.e.:
https://wseiitenglish.wordpress.com/2014/11/16/limit-up-to-128gb-of-memory-on-32bit-windows/

Not sure how this would apply to a VM though.

Comment: @DennisNolte But no single 32-bit application can use more than 4GB of RAM (and usually much less) so it's often useless.